# Convert NumPy object array to datetime64

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, datetime, type-conversion

```
data['RealTime'][:,0]
Out[23]: 
array([datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 12, 18, 13, 8, 826000),
       datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 12, 18, 13, 8, 846000),
       datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 12, 18, 13, 8, 866000), ...,
       datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 12, 18, 30, 40, 186000),
       datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 12, 18, 30, 40, 206000),
       datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 12, 18, 30, 40, 226000)], dtype=object)
```

how can I convert into an array of dtype datetime?

Comment: Is this Pandas or Numpy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know you have `pandas`, so you can just use `pd.to_datetime`:

```
out = pd.to_datetime(array)
print(out)

DatetimeIndex(['2017-09-12 18:13:08.826000', '2017-09-12 18:13:08.846000',
               '2017-09-12 18:13:08.866000', '2017-09-12 18:30:40.186000',
               '2017-09-12 18:30:40.206000', '2017-09-12 18:30:40.226000'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

You can retrieve a `numpy` array from `out` by accessing `out.values`.

---

With `numpy`, you'd do the same thing using `astype`:

```
out = array.astype("datetime64[ns]")
print(out)

array(['2017-09-12T18:13:08.826000000', '2017-09-12T18:13:08.846000000',
       '2017-09-12T18:13:08.866000000', '2017-09-12T18:30:40.186000000',
       '2017-09-12T18:30:40.206000000', '2017-09-12T18:30:40.226000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```